# Bidirectional mapping null value is persisted in parent reference column in child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Parent Entity

Employer (parent)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

 @OneToMany( mappedBy = "employer",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Employee> empDetails = new ArrayList<>();
```

Employee (child)

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="emp_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employer employer;
```

Json from postman

```
{
    "name" : "data",
    "empDetails":[{
        "firstName" : "ttest",
        "lastName" : "te"
    }]
}
```

I'am trying to save in single save call like. Once parent is saved then child will be persisted automatically . But while doing so parent reference in child column is inserted with null.

Comment: mappedBy = "employer"

Comment: that was an typo. now i updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will not set *employer* value in your Employee instances. You should set them manually in controller:

```
    employer.getEmpDetails().forEach(e -> e.setEmployer(employer));
```

Answer (score 2):

mappedBy = "employer"

And here comes additional unneccessary text so I can post this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference in a way, the parent object in the child object in order to persist the id's parent correctly.

I think you have something like that:

```
Employer employer = new Employer("Employer");
Employee empX = new Employee("Employee 1", "My lastname")
employer.getEmpDetails().add(empX);
```

You could extend the constructor and set the parent reference:

```
Employer employer = new Employer("Employer");
Employee empX = new Employee("Employee 1", "My lastname", employer)
employer.getEmpDetails().add(empX);
```

Comment: maybe is why you are using `mappedBy = "employee"` but actually should be `mappedBy = "employer"`